# ExpiresDefault: difference between Access and Modificaion?

Tags: caching, .htaccess, proxy, performance, cache-control

I have been trying to decode the actual, benefitial differences between the **Access** and **Modification**, when setting **Cache control** in Apache's **.htaccess**, when to use which, but find the Apache documentation too technical for my understanding.

Basically, I want to use a method that gives me good fast caching. Can someone explain the advantages of using access as opposed to modification? When to use which?

Does  A7200  mean *"keep 2 hours after last user accessed it"*?

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
```

Does  M7200  mean *"keep 2 hours after the file was modified on server"*?

```
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 10 years"
```

I have a bunch of dynamic files (php|htm) and a bunch of static files (ico|jpg|png|gif|svg|swf|css|js|fon|ttf|eot|xml|pdf|flv) and cannot make up my mind what to do. Thanks very much for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access refers to the last time a client's web browser requested the file
Modification refers to the last time the webpage changed (HTML) or was generated (PHP)

If you say Expiresdefault "access plus 2 days" it means that when a user downloads a file from Apache, that file stays in the Apache cache for 2 days unless another user requests the same file and on and on...

Access plus 2 days should be good enough, 10 years seems very excessive.

Comment: I am bit confuse here , here it is something like that my browser will check for modification at server after every 2 days and will cache new site version?